# Is there any way to do a for each all Google Forms created by a Gmail account?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I am trying to get a list with all the google forms created by a specific google account (my own Gmail account BTW), in order to list them, get each ID and after that, be able to extract the responses spreadsheet associated to it and consolidate everything in a big home-made merge table.

I have tried using `FormApp`, but it appears to be only for just one form.
I have tried filtering all the existing files in `DriveApp`, but no luck at all.

Comment: Have you tried Drve.Files.List with a query that searches for Application/vnd.google.apps.form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DriveApp.getFilesByType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbytypemimetype) to get all Google Forms in your drive using [MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type?hl=en).

Once you get all the forms, you can check its owner's email address using [File.getOwner()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getowner) [User.getEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/user#getemail) before listing all your File Ids'.

After that, you can open each form using [FormApp.openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#openbyidid) and use [Form.getDestinationId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getdestinationid) to get the response destination.

**Sample Code:**

```
  var formList = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS);
  var myForms = [];
  while (formList.hasNext()) {
    var form = formList.next();
    var ownerEmail = form.getOwner().getEmail();
    Logger.log(form.getName());
    Logger.log(ownerEmail);

    if(ownerEmail == "myEmail@example.com"){
      myForms.push(form.getId());
    }
  }

  myForms.forEach(id=>{
    var form = FormApp.openById(id);
    var destinationId = form.getDestinationId();
    var destinationType = form.getDestinationType();
    Logger.log(destinationId);
    Logger.log(destinationType);
  })
```